# Different image quality for different zoom levels (OpenLayers/GeoServer)?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, image, png

Original data that raster layers are made of are of a high quality. At a small scale (1:100) this is useful. However at a large scale (1:10 000) it results in ~300KB PNG images which are actually not needed to be of that good of a quality. I am looking for an approach to have cached raster layers where one group of zoom levels (lets say range from 11 to 20) images would have different (lower quality) than it should based on original high quality data.

Comment: When you say "not needed to be that good" are you worried about tile production time, disk space, or something else?  There are so many fewer tiles at lower zoom levelrs that the actual disk space saved for lower quality tiles will be small; similarly the data processing required to render a low or high quality tile is going to be the same - or am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you using WMS service? Raster image output that has the same WIDTH and HEIGHT should not be very much bigger at scale 1:10000 than at scale 1:100 but the compression ratio of png does depend on source data. Large areas with uniform color compress better and you may have such data at scale 1:100. There is a WMS service level setting for PNG and JPEG quality in GeoServer but values cannot be changed dynamically. Have you tried jpeg format?

Comment: @SomeoneElse Just trying to decrease amount of image data that needs to be sent to client browser.

Comment: @user30184 Yep, using WMS. Images must have transparent feature so JPEG is not an opotion if I am not wrong. To change PNG quality in GeoServer you mean to change "Compression level"? Won't that affect image quality for the images at 1:100? At the moment I am thinking about caching layers as usual and then manually launching a script/tool to affect PNG image quality at desired zoom levels in the hard drive.

Comment: The png quality setting is global for all scales and you should not await that it would make miracles. Test with GDAL png driver http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html with z=1 made 5129878 byte output from a topographic map while z=9 compressed it into 4621972 bytes. But I would like to see screen captures or sample files about what you consider high quality and lower quality.